# What's the word for a photo that is next to a recipe?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word that describes a photo of food/meal that is included in a recipe but it is not a real photo of the food.

I found "illustrative photo" next to some pictures on reuters.com and Google nGrams says this collocation exits but COCA found only 1 hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a word that describes the food but it is not the real photo of that food. Do you mean that if the recipe is of making a 'cake' but you show a photo of some cake which is not the one that is the result of the recipe?

If yes, the word 'illustrative' is *okay*.

> *[illustrative](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=illustrative)* - serving to demonstrate

So, if you put an illustrative image/photo of a cake which is not the same as a result of that recipe but gives an *idea* how does it look, it's okay!

Comment: You got it exactly right! Thanks a million cause you saved the day again, Maulik!